# EXPLAIN SELECT to return number of rows of non-distinct columns value

Tags: mysql, select, count, explain

there is primary id 'VOTERID'
having distinct values
its easy to count it easily with EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM master
its very quick to query, as you saw on dashboard page
how fast it is loading
in the same way, I want to count rows for STATUS colmun, not having distinct values
so ,  EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM master  where STATUS='A' fails and returns all rows coun
*count
while, I just want to return rows count where STATUS='A'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of rows for a `status` value, why are you using `explain`?  You should simply use `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from master
where status = 'A';
```

You should use explain for its intended purpose -- understanding how a query is being processed.  If you want real result, run a query.

Comment: Appreciation for your response .Gordon. But, I want to do count over millions of rows and this normal count function don't work for me. It is killing due to delayed execution time. I need this to be quick. I appreciate for your great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3139692 . . . MySQL is not at all shy about (1) calling the value an estimate and (2) saying that it is about rows being examined not returned.  Try reading the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows).